# Android Changing CheckBox Checked Color

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm coding an application that deals with 2 different `CheckBoxes`. When one `CheckBox` gets clicked, the color of the tick should be blue (instead of green), whereas the color of the other `CheckBox` remains green.

This is my code...

```
CheckBox green = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.greenButton);
CheckBox blue = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.blueButton);

blue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        if(arg1){
            blue.setHighlightColor(Color.BLUE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Question Marked As Partial", 4000).show();
        }
    }
});

green.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        if(arg1){
            blue.setHighlightColor(Color.GREEN);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Question Marked As Fully Understood!", 4000).show();
        }
    }
});
```

However, both the `CheckBoxes` tick colors remains green, and the `Toast` message doesn't get displayed, so I am guessing that the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is never being called.

Could someone offer any advice?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code, or adding some `System.out.println()` statements, to check that your code is definately being called. My guess is that this whole piece of code isn't even being called (so the listeners aren't getting placed on the checkboxes), rather than it being a problem with the actual listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Toast` isn't appearing, it is possible that your listeners aren't actually being set on the `CheckBoxes`. In other words, maybe this whole piece of code isn't even being called.

If your code is in a method, make sure you're calling the method to set the listeners on the `CheckBoxes`, or ensure this code is in one of your main methods such as `onCreate()`.

If you don't know already, it would be a great time to learn how to debug your code - it makes it really quick and easy to determine whether your code is being called or not.